# SSL error sign in cerfied domain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

In the beginning purchasing SSL cerficate for my domain, it was a "green lock button" instead of "grey with attention" sign.

screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj10v.png]

What does it means or how can i make it green again? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you would see if you look at the other tab in that popup, your page has some resources which were not served over HTTPS.

Use the dev tools to find them, and change them to all use HTTP URLs.

Comment: shit, it was my logo which was hosted to blooger and linked as http:// instead of https://